# Checking if two users belong to the same conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database containing `users` `conversations` `conversation_user`.

Now I want to find out if two users are having a conversation. How can I do this in a smart way?

In this case, `user1` and `user2` are having a conversation.

[image]

Comment: What code do you have at the moment?

Comment: What's the `id` column for if the pair `(conversation_id,user_id)` should be unique?

Comment: To the downvoters - how is this not a real question?

Comment: Because you're posing a problem and asking people to solve it for you. What have you tried? What problems did you run into? This site is to help you do your job, not to do your job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list all `conversation_id` that user 1 and user 2 have in common:

```
SELECT   conversation_id
FROM     conversations
WHERE    user_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)=2
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/068a0/1).

Comment: This is working just perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
select count('x') 
from 
  conversation_user x
where
  (x.userid1 = 1 and x.userid2 = 2) or  
  (x.userid1 = 2 and x.userid2 = 1)
```

If this query returns `0`, then they are not having a conversation. Otherwise they are.

Answer (score 0):

A self join could do it:

```
SELECT c.conversation_id
FROM conversations c
JOIN conversations c2
    ON c.conversation_id=c2.conversation_id
WHERE c.user_id=<x> AND c2.user_id=<y>
```